# How to set and get JSON.parse(request.data) in global variable in postman?

Tags: javascript, postman-testcase

Can anyone let me know how to set and get the 'request.data' into a global variable as I am intended to access the request body of a post request in a subsequent get request later?

I tried the below, but this is not working.

```
pm.globals.set("reqBody", JSON.parse(request.data));

pm.expect(response.name).to.equal(pm.globals.get(reqBody.pr_practice_name))
```

Comment: "is not working" is a useless problem description. What is the result, exactly? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I get the below error: "ReferenceError: reqBody is not defined"

Comment: I understand reqBody is of type object, So I can understand that I am missing something in the get() method above in order to access the object properties. Could you let me know how to get this?

Comment: My guess is you need `pm.globals.get("reqBody").pr_practice_name`

Answer (score 1):

As Chris G replied above, the following resolved my issue:

```
pm.globals.get("reqBody").pr_practice_name
```